# codename one picker object

Tags: codenameone, picker

Do pickers only works with strings? It's not possible to use a generic class overriding the method toString? 
I use this technique in Java with ComboBox. For example, if a user must choose a employee I create a class with two parameters `int code` and `String name` and a method `toString()` and populate the ComboBox with objects from that class. The user chooses seeing the names and I can get the code of chosen employee casting the `getSelectedItem()` to the class created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pickers map to OS native calls which provide deep native integration with the OS e.g. a time picker on Android looks like this:

[image]

So [Picker](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/spinner/Picker.html) effectively supports time, date, numbers or Strings as anything more elaborate can't be expressed natively in a reasonable way.

You can use the `ComboBox` class which is pretty similar to what Swing has and has it's own renderer but it might feel unnatural on the device. Personally I would just use a button and show a popup `Dialog` when it's pressed if you need customizable capabilities.